# R Read table, keep quotes in string

Tags: r

For example, I have a file with the following contents:

```
x=setwd('./blabla/bla'); system('python ........');
b=1,2,3
...
```

This is a list of stuff of a problem which I need to keep and process later on.

I need to use read table, but the problem I'm having is that the string loses the quotes and becomes:

```
setwd(./blabla/bla);
```

How can I keep the quotes by reading with read.table? If I use `quote=""`, it gives me an error:

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
>       line 1 did not have 4 elements

Comment: It's not clear what happened to the `x=`. If you do a quick `?read.table` in the console, you'll see `quote:  
the set of quoting characters. To disable quoting altogether, use quote = "". See scan for the behaviour on quotes embedded in quotes. Quoting is only considered for columns read as character, which is all of them unless colClasses is specified` so using `quote=""` in the call should work.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `read.table` and no `source`? I can't reproduce this but you can try `read.table(..., quote = "")`

Comment: This looks more like a job for `source`. What do you want to do with the file contents after import?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I've used the quote="" argument but i guess the problem I have is that there are multiple instructions with quotes per line. I'm going to eval the contents after import.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I needed to store the instructions in the following way:

```
x="setwd('./blabla/bla'); system('python ........');"
```